# What does it mean "to have claim over something"?

Tags: idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

This is a sentence from the book Everything I Know About Love:

I thought we had claim over each other’s twenties before we’d inevitably have to give the other one up.

Comment: It essentially is referring to a legal claim, as in ownership.  It's being metaphoric or maybe hyperbolic.  It's suggesting that they would own each other's 20's, that throughout their ages 20 through 29, they'd have each other.

Answer (score 1):

**claim (something) for (oneself or something)**  [TDF](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/claim) an idiom

> To declare **something** as one's property or jurisdiction.

In this case it appear to reference youth or the age of the twenties.